# How to transform an HTMLCollection object to a String with XML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, string

What is the best way to get the full String representation of an HTMLCollection object in `javascript/jquery?` The output String should have an XML syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div/>').append(HTMLCollection).html(); // Retrieves the `outerHTML`
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer but it didn't work for me. I get a TypeError: this[0].innerHTML is undefined. This object is set though, as it has a length of 66. Apparently the HTMLCollection isn't in HTML but in XML, as it actually is a SOAP response from a web service. Any ideas on how to get a string out of this?

Comment: Given what you've said, the only reliable way of doing this is to iterate through each node and build up a string. May I ask what purpose this string is to serve?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.adahas.com/2005/05/innerhtml-in-applicationxhtmlxml/

Comment: I am actually creating a javascript app that has to modify a SOAP response from a SharePoint web service and use it call another one. That call is made though an API (SPAPI) that requires strings as parameters. I have found a way build my string using firefox, but it doesn't seems to work with IE. Here it is:

var xmlDoc = wsResponse.responseXML;
var xmlFields = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FieldInformation");
var xml = new XMLSerializer();
var string = "";
for(var i=0; i<xmlFields.length; i++){
 string = string + xml.serializeToString($(xmlFields)[i]);
}

Answer (score 0):

My guess is to first clone the node's before trying the div trick:

```
$('<div/>').append($(HTMLCollection).clone()).html();
```

Without cloning, the reassignment of the elements of the collection to the newly created div will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Considering jQuery [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and .outerHTML() returns the first matched element of a set of elements you may use .outerHTML(function(index, outerHTML)) from https://github.com/darlesson/jquery-outerhtml to do something like:

Consider the following HTML:

```
<span>One</span>
<span>Two</span>
<span>Three</span>
```

Consider this call:

```
var allHTML = "";

$("span").outerHTML(function(index, outerHTML){
    allHTML = allHTML + outerHTML;
});
```

allHTML variable is equal "<span>One</span><span>Two</span><span>Three</span>".